# PHP Detect if current stdout support ANSI escape chars

Tags: php, stdout, ansi-escape

Let's have following script:

```
echo "Hello world\e[5Dmoon!";
```

Using `PHP_SAPI` I am able to determine if script is running on CLI or on WEB.

If script is executed from command line, it will output `Hello moon!`. But output of script can be forwarded to e.g. text file, like `php test.php > output.txt`. And if output is forwarded, escape chars won't work and output will be `Hello world^[[5Dmoon`.

How to determine, if current stdout supports ANSI escape chars, to avoid "spamming" output which does not support this?

Comment: With `php test.php > output.txt` you are _still_ writing to stdout. Passing the content of that buffer on into the textfile, only happens afterwards with the `> output.txt` part.

Comment: This is how Symfony console does it: https://github.com/symfony/console/blob/d1d8b8fd9b605630aa73b1b384e246fee54e8ffa/Output/StreamOutput.php#L94

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are searching for should be `stream_isatty(STDOUT)`.

It returns correct values for your use case - web false, terminal true, output in TXT false.